# Can "if" be used in the sense "albeit"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I'm reading an English text written by a non-native speaker of English, and now I've come across the following:

> This idea will be discussed again later on, if from a different point of view.

Now I'm wondering whether this use of *if* is correct? The intended meaning is 'albeit', and personally, I would prefer this word in place of *if*, but perhaps *if* is just as correct?

Thanks again :)

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58646/usage-of-if-and-if-not-to-mean-and-perhaps-even-also).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If can be used in place of albeit in certain circumstances but it is usually (if not always) followed by but.

> It was a song, if but a quiet song.

In the example you have provided here, if does not follow grammatically and you should use albeit.

Comment: The OP's example seems fine to me. In your example, _but_ seems to mean _only_.